# Copy file and images from a buffer

Tags: c++, file-io, buffer

I need to write a copyFile function which will copy both, regular files and images.

The problem is that I have to use an external API to open the file, and it can only pass me a "buffer" (char* buffer) which contains the file.

I can't find a solution anywhere, so I need your help.

I tried something like this:

```
bool fileManager::copyFile(const char* tempFileName, int bufferSize, char* fBuffer){
    if (!fileExists(tempFileName)){
        ofstream outfile(tempFileName,ofstream::binary);
        outfile.write(fBuffer,bufferSize);
        outfile.close();
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I copy an image instead of a file any of the image viewer can open it.

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem? Can open or can't open?

Comment: Is the image data being passed to you via this API raw image data? If so, you would need to prepend a format (.jpeg, .png, etc..) header and format the data accordingly.

Comment: It is impossible to open the image copied. I receive an improper image header error. No, the image is passed as char*, so I think there is the content of the file, indipendently from the fileType. Hope this is more clear.